# Extracting GPS data from GoPro for each video frame

Tags: python, gps, gopro

I have a GoPro video that includes GPS data in the mp4 file. Now using a Python script I want to extract every single frame of that video and save the respective GPS coordinates of each frame. I found a Python library [pygpmf](https://github.com/alexis-mignon/pygpmf), which helps to extract the GPS data from the video. That works quite well so far, the GPS data can be extracted as XML file in this format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="gpx.py -- https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy">
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="44.1287283" lon="5.427715">
        <ele>833.759</ele>
        <time>2020-07-03T12:36:56.940000Z</time>
        <sym>Square</sym>
        <fix>3d</fix>
        <pdop>1.82</pdop>
        <extensions>
          <speed_2d>
            <value>9.221</value>
            <unit>m/s</unit>
          </speed_2d>
          <speed_3d>
            <value>9.25</value>
            <unit>m/s</unit>
          </speed_3d>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
      ...
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

That looks fine, however, I cannot see how I can link a frame to that list of GPS coordinates. Is there any way I am missing here? Or is there another library better suited for this job? Or do you have any other idea how I can get that GPS data per frame?

Comment: You apparently have time up to 1/100 of second (`2020-07-03T12:36:56.940000Z`), can not you use it to decude to which frame this location belong?

Comment: Well, I could try to link these time steps with the video meta data. I was hoping though there is an "official" way how one can get GPS data for each frame.